# What technology is used in this Visual Studio installer?

Tags: wpf, visual-studio, installation

Here's a screenshot of the [installer](http://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/products/visual-studio-express-vs.aspx):

[image: Visual Studio screenshot]

**How was this created?** It doesn't seem to use any of the already established technologies (InstallShield, NSIS, InnoSetup, WiX, etc).

By the looks it seems a normal WPF application. **Does Microsoft have some framework or something to create installers like this one?**

It kinda seems to me that they recommend using MSIs, but they use something totally different to create their own installers.

Besides there's [this post by Joel Spolsky](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/RandomStuff/FB30SetupSpec.htm) regarding creating your own installers. **So should I go against the flow and create my own installer instead of using existing technologies (which are kind of limited)?**

Comment: It doesn't have anything to do with an installer of course, it is just a pretty face.  MSI, like almost all Microsoft programs, strongly [supports Automation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa367809%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).